# Aesthetics and bang-bang in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I am trying to write a function that creates a barplot but I have trouble getting the `fill` aesthetic right.

- If I use `fill = !!x` leads to `Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.`
- and `fill = x` leads to `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): fill`

My Code:

```
genBar <- function(data, x, y) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  plot <- ggplot(data) +
    geom_bar(aes(!!x, !!y),
             stat = 'identity',
             fill = <help>) 
  return(plot)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fill` should be inside `aes`. Try :

```
library(ggplot2)

genBar <- function(data, x, y) {
  plot <- ggplot(data) +
    geom_bar(aes({{x}}, {{y}}, fill = {{x}}),
             stat = 'identity') 
  return(plot)
}

genBar(mtcars, cyl, mpg)
```

---

If you want to pass column names as string use `.data` pronoun.

```
genBar <- function(data, x, y) {
  plot <- ggplot(data) +
    geom_bar(aes(.data[[x]], .data[[y]], fill = .data[[x]]),
             stat = 'identity') 
  return(plot)
}

genBar(mtcars, "cyl", "mpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

genBar <- function(data, x, y) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  plot <- ggplot(data) +
    geom_bar(aes(!!x, !!y, fill = !!x),
             stat = 'identity') 
  return(plot)
}

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarize(Size = mean(Petal.Length)) %>%
  genBar(Species, Size)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I got around it by adding 
```c <- data %>% select(!!x)
  col <- 1:length(c[[1]]) ```
but this is much cleaner